# C a variable from struct tm dissapears

Tags: c, date

I'm writing a program in which i get the current week number and the current year number and use them later in other functions. I noticed at some point that the  current week number which i saved in `Day.weekNumb` in the `struct WYDay date_retrieval()` functon doesn't show anymore and can't use it but i was able to locate at which line it dissapears. In the line in which the data dissapears i tried to put a NULL terminator at the end of a string so it can be used without problems later on. I've put 2 `printf()` before and after the line to see that the variable shows nothing after the line executes.

I know my code is messy right now but i'm trying to make it work for the moment. I've entered all the functions in which i think i may have screwed something up. Help is appreciated in helping and understanding the problem.

```
struct WYDay
{
    char yearNumb[4];
    char weekNumb;
};



int main ()
{
char usrOption;

int fileExists = 0;
int *randValues = NULL;

struct WYDay Days;

puts("This is the math and programming schedule check!\n"
       "Would you like to see what you've done this week or add something? 
\n\n"
       "1.See your progress!\n2.Check what you've done!\n\n\n");

usrOption = user_input();
Days = date_retrieval();
fileExists = first_time_date_check(Days);
if(Days.weekNumb == '1' || fileExists == 0)
{

    randValues = schedule_rand();
    date_save(Days);
}
file_manip(Days, fileExists, randValues, usrOption);

if(randValues != NULL)
{
    free(randValues);
}

printf("\n{%c}\n", Days.weekNumb);

return 0;
}



struct WYDay date_retrieval()
{
char *yearNumbP;

int iterat = 0;

time_t currentDate;

struct WYDay Day;
struct tm *Date;

time(&currentDate);
Date = localtime(&currentDate);

Day.weekNumb = week_day(Date);
yearNumbP = year_day(Date);

for(iterat = 0; iterat < 4; iterat++)
{
    Day.yearNumb[iterat] = yearNumbP[iterat];
}

printf("\n{%c}\n", Day.weekNumb);
Day.yearNumb[4] = '\0';       /*This line does something to the week number*/
printf("\n{%c}\n", Day.weekNumb);

free(yearNumbP);

return Day;
}



char week_day(struct tm *Date)
{
char numbOfWeekDay[2];
char weekDay;

strftime(numbOfWeekDay, 2, "%w", Date);

weekDay = numbOfWeekDay[0];
if(weekDay == '0')
{
    weekDay = '7';
}

return weekDay;
}



char *year_day(struct tm *Date)
{
char *numbOfYearDay = calloc(4, sizeof(char));

strftime(numbOfYearDay, 4, "%j", Date);

return numbOfYearDay;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with this code, but the `yearNumb[4]` overflow is probably the main one. Turning on all compiler warnings, or running valgrind or an address sanitizer if you can, might help you catch this sort of error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring `weekNumb` and `yearNumb` as characters?  Common practice would be to declare them as integers.  They're generally easier to manipulate that way.

Comment: There's no particular reason i just didn't know it's better to declare them as integers. I've fixed it and it works, thanks for all your help. Now i have to fix other issues that arose with the program. If can't i'll ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code declares the `Day.yearNumb` array as being an array of four elements:

```
char yearNumb[4];
```

But, it is setting the 5th element of a 4 element array:

```
Day.yearNumb[4] = '\0';
```

(Remember the elements are numbered starting from 0!) So, this code exhibits undefined behaviour. Most likely what is actually happening is that the next structure member is getting set to 0.

You need an extra element in yearNumb, so that it can hold 5 characters - the four characters of the year, plus the nul terminator.

Answer (score 0):

This is defining an array of 4 elements.

```
char yearNumb[4];
```

This is accessing the 5th element in that array.

```
Day.yearNumb[4] = '\0';
```

So naturally by putting a value in a place beyond the end of your array, you'll be affecting whatever comes after it in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave memory for the terminating `'\0'`. Otherwise it will overflow in memory over the next element in it.

```
struct WYDay
{
    char yearNumb[5];
    char weekNumb[2];
};
```

Now `yearNumb[4] = '\0'` works. You can also do `weekNumb[1] = '\0'`

Comment: There can be 52 (53, in fact, according to ISO 8601) weeks in a year; the week number needs to be at least 3 bytes long if the trailing null is to be present.

Comment: No. `weekNumb` holds values 0..6 designating the day of the week.

Comment: It is confusing, then.  Why use string representation for year and not for other numbers.  However, it’s also not critical until others have to understand the code too.

Comment: I'm just looking at the `week_day` function.